# JSP custom tags null value

Tags: jsp, taglib

I'm facing a problem with my own jsp tag. I want it to allow null-values, but if I want to give null-values to my handler, the value is 0 and not null.

My Handler:

```
public class BigDecimalStripper extends SimpleTagSupport {

private BigDecimal numberToStrip;

public void setNumberToStrip(BigDecimal numberToStrip) {
    this.numberToStrip = numberToStrip;
}

@Override
public void doTag() throws JspException, IOException {
    if (numberToStrip == null) {
        return;
    }
    JspWriter out = getJspContext().getOut();
    BigDecimal withoutTrailingZeros = numberToStrip.stripTrailingZeros();
    String formattedNumber = withoutTrailingZeros.toPlainString();
    out.println(formattedNumber);
}
}
```

My taglib:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<taglib>
<tlib-version>1.0</tlib-version>
<jsp-version>2.0</jsp-version>
<short-name>Fishie JSP Utils</short-name>
<tag>
    <name>BigDecimalStrip</name>
    <tag-class>ch.fishie.jsp.utils.BigDecimalStripper</tag-class>
    <body-content>scriptless</body-content>
    <attribute>
        <name>numberToStrip</name>
        <required>true</required>
        <rtexprvalue>true</rtexprvalue>
    </attribute>
</tag>
```

My JSP-code:

```
 <c:forEach items="${pagination.pageEntries}" var="aquarium">
                    <tr>
                        <td class="name"><c:out value="${aquarium.name}" /></td>
                        <td class="length"><fu:BigDecimalStrip numberToStrip="${aquarium.length}" /></td>
 .....
```

aquarium.length is null, but when it is set into the `BigDecimalStripper`, it is 0.
Does someone see the mistake I make?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tomcat's built in EL parser will do that for all classes extending Number.
You must be using Tomcat 6.0.16 or later, try this...

`-Dorg.apache.el.parser.COERCE_TO_ZERO=false`

Answer (score 0):

COERCE_TO_ZERO parameter in accepted answer changed nothing on my setup (Tomcat 7.0.40, Liferay 6.1.2), but blog [How To Pass A Null Value To A Custom Tag Library](https://www.kayley.name/2011/09/27/how-to-pass-a-null-value-to-a-custom-tag-library/) trick did.

Replace `BigDecimal` with `Object` in tag attribute setter parameter (`setNumberToStrip`) and cast to `BigDecimal` before storing in field. Perform *instanceof* or *null* checks if necessary.

```java
public void setNumberToStrip(Object numberToStrip) {
    if (value instanceof BigDecimal || value == null) {
        this.numberToStrip = (BigDecimal) numberToStrip;
    }
}
```